# USB short protection

Tags: mac, usb, hardware

I was prototyping some USB things and I was wondering if the Mac USB ports have any short-circut protection.

---

If I were to connect Vcc and GND directly together would it break my Mac? Would the motherboard be borked?

[image]

---

Specifically, I'm using a Mid-2012 Retina 15" MacBook Pro and am looking to know if it has any protection or resilience against damage of this sort?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and it should probably be asked on the [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site.

Comment: @IconDaemon this doesn't have anything to do with Electrical Engineering. I'm asking simply about the protection placed on a Mac's USB port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the Mac does detect and prevent shorting. I'm not sure to what extent but this little box pops up:

[image: USB Devices Disabled]

Once power is back to normal, the Mac will resume serving power to the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

OS X should identify the port as having high current draw and shut it down until you unplug the device.

Source: I was doing exactly this and ended up accidentally shorting the Vcc and ground pins, and got a notification center message saying this.

Comment: It's great that you've personally experimented on this, but can you please provide more information? Did you see the message in Terminal? Because, personally I don't think OS X should know anything about currents or voltages on the motherboard.

Comment: Edited.  USB hosts and devices negotiate a maximum power draw when plugged in, so it's reasonable to believe that the computer would have a way to verify that. It could also be monitoring on a larger scale, checking the current draw of the motherboard itself and deciding excess load is caused by a faulty USB device.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in a Mac lab I support we had a USB extension cable that someone had rolled over with a chair. The outside of the connector was bent in so it was shorting one of the pins.

It caused an alert window to pop up with the message DudeOfAwesome's describing. When the cable was replaced, it was fine. The machine never had any problems with the USB bus afterwards.